# Eclipse and Git integration fails on Windows XP

Tags: eclipse, git, windows-xp, egit

---

I'm starting using Git as VCS. I've installed it locally on my machine, Windows XP sp3 Professional. Everything is ok with installation and configuration.

Problems occurs when I try to integrate Git with Eclipse (Kepler). I´ve installed Egit plugin. Then when I try to clone from a local bare repository, I follow these steps:

- Open an Eclipse workspace
- Right click on project explorer
- Choose import
- Choose projects from Git
- Next-> choose clone URI
- Next-> browse to repository location
- Next-> browse to destination location
- Next-> "Problem ocuured"

When I almost finish I got an error message:

```
Git repository clone failed.
Symbolic links not supported on this operating system
```

I try the solution from this page http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html

but didn't work for me.

Is there a way to make symbolic links work on Windows XP or a different way to make Egit works on windows XP?

Hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: After April 8, 2014, technical assistance from Microsoft for Windows XP will no longer be available. I would recommend going to another platform.

Comment: Just did an update to EGit and it immediately failed on all operations with this error. (Presumably it affects all versions of Windows so giving Microsoft money won't fix this.)

Comment: After many changes, uninstalling plugins, I broke the IDE. So I had to re-install Eclipse from scratch. I chose Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 for java EE Developers, that already had Egit 3.2 installed, made some test and everything worked perfect

Comment: @MichaelVer Oh ! Thank you for your very useful recommendation, we should have thought about it :roll: Do you propose to give us money for Windows license and new compatible hardware? So kind of you. Anyway I have the same issue with Eclipse 4.5 upgraded to 4.5.1... but I don't know if the upgrade is part of the problem. Of course I use WinXP...